# Can't vote to reopen a re-closed question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-reopen

Five people, including myself, voted to reopen a closed question, and it was therefore reopened. Shortly thereafter, a moderator unilaterally re-closed the question using a different close reason. I believe the new reason is also invalid, so I would like to vote to reopen the question again. When I click the "reopen" link, however, I get an error message: **You have already voted to reopen this question**.

It seems clear to me that my vote to reopen the question after the first closure should not prevent me from voting to reopen the question after a second closure for a completely different (and, in my opinion, also invalid) reason. No one wants more edit wars, but my vote is only one of five that are necessary to reopen a question, and the way things are structured now seems ripe for misuse.

Comment: @cVplZ - I don't know anything of the sort. It seems stupid to intentionally design the system this way, so I assume it's a bug.

Answer (score 10):

Back in the old days, in the long-long-ago period that no one remembers or if they do believes actually existed outside of their own fevered imaginations...

...Folks got into "close wars". Someone would close a post. Someone else would reopen it. Then the first person would close it again, and the second reopen again. This went on and on.

This irritated folks. A lot. So a complicated array of belts and suspenders were attached to prevent it.

The restriction on casting multiple close or reopen votes for a single question is but *one* of the brightly-colored elastic bands holding up the metaphorical trousers here. Its presence, ridiculous though it may appear, is wholly intentional.

If you strongly believe that a given question should be reopened but have already voted and can vote no more... Raise the issue on meta. It may be that others, who have not already voted, will agree with you if you are sufficiently persuasive in your call to action.

#### Tangentially related: [I Move to Close This Question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/i-move-to-close-this-question/)

Comment: Well explained, I could imagine that these pointless 'close-reopen wars' would have seriously wasted people's time and detracted from the main purpose of the site - questions and answers.

Comment: I understand the reasoning for close/reopen votes being a one time use, but we're talking about a moderator here undoing it, who has unlimited votes. Sometimes  I've seen, and one time just yesterday, a mod hammer close was reopened by the community only to have the mod close it again.

Answer (score 4):

The same person cannot vote to close or reopen a question more than once. That's just the way it is. I'm pretty sure the reason is so that one small group of people can't force their opinion against community consensus.